# c# asp.net how to call a dll from an iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I have a dll that is being called like this:

```
http://xxxx/dllFile.dll
```

for security reasons, I want to hide the dll call from the browser, I asked the company that developed that page to hide that dll call and this is their answer:

```
There’s no development to hidden the url for the “chat.dll”.

The most simple is making an alternative start page. On this page have an “IFrame” and inside will contain the complete chat. Thus hidden all chats urls, and show only the URL from the start page.
```

so I started working on their suggesting.
I have iframe like this:

```
<iframe>

    </iframe>
```

and **my question** is how to call that dll file from this iframe?

thanks

Comment: `<iframe src="http://xxxx/dllFile.dll">` ?

Comment: @AlexK. thank, let me try it and update you

Comment: @AlexK. I am getting 404 page not found, I did this url: ` <iframe src="http:/192.168.1.102/chat">` where `192.168.1.102` is the server where I call that dll. plus, when I go to browser and call `http://192.168.1.102/chat/` I got the page

Comment: @AlexK. it is working now, please write an answer to accept it many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell the `iframe` to load its content from a url, just set its `src` attribute:

```
<iframe src="http://xxxx/dllFile.dll">
```